# Sqlite3 asynchronous insertion and updates

Tags: c#, android, android-asynctask, sqlite

Im having a great deal of trouble with inserting into this sqlite database. first of the first peice of code is the items i insert the first time around, the 2nd piece of code is the items i want to insert around. The first time i insert all is well and i can retrieve the rows just fine, but the 2nd time i try to insert new items into the db it is not updated, instead a sqliteexception is throw with the message constraint.

1st time

```
GroceriesItemHistory.AddToGroceriesHistory ("Banana");
GroceriesItemHistory.AddToGroceriesHistory ("Apple");
GroceriesItemHistory.AddToGroceriesHistory ("Citrus");
```

2nd time

```
GroceriesItemHistory.AddToGroceriesHistory ("Banana");
GroceriesItemHistory.AddToGroceriesHistory ("Apple");
GroceriesItemHistory.AddToGroceriesHistory ("Citrus");
GroceriesItemHistory.AddToGroceriesHistory ("Plant");
```

Here you see the code that calls the db to save the items

```
saveHistory.Click += delegate 
{
    Task<string> result = localDB.SaveGroceriesItemHistory();
    Toast.MakeText(this, result.Result, ToastLength.Short).Show();
};
```

Here is the actual code that inserts the items

```
public async Task<string> SaveGroceriesItemHistory()
{
    try
    {
        var dbConn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        foreach (var historyItem in GroceriesItemHistory.GroceriesHistory)
        {
            HistoryItem item = new HistoryItem();

            item.HistoryItemName = historyItem.Key;
            item.NumberOfAddidtions = historyItem.Value;

            if(await dbConn.InsertAsync(item) != 0)
                await dbConn.UpdateAsync(item);
        }
        return "GroceriesItemHistory saved!";
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright i fixed the issue by first quering the db if the row existed with the same primary key of the object i wanted to insert

```
if(await dbConn.FindAsync<HistoryItem>(x => x.HistoryItemName == item.HistoryItemName) != null)
    await dbConn.UpdateAsync(item);
else
    await dbConn.InsertAsync(item);
```